Find the version of an R package on CRAN
In documents I want to be able to refer to the version of a package installed on CRAN, which may be behind the version I currently have installed.
I can do this using available.packages(), but this downloads the entire CRAN package list (350K lines, 10Mb), so I wonder if there is something simpler.
#' Find version of a package on CRAN
cran_version <- function(package) {
  avail <- utils::available.packages(filters = "CRAN")
  avail <- avail[, c("Package", "Version")]
  which <- avail[, "Package"] == package
  avail[which, "Version"]
}

> packageVersion("heplots")
[1] ‘1.6.3’
> cran_version("heplots")
[1] "1.6.2"


Why not simply available.packages(repos = "https://cran.r-project.org/")[package, "Version"]?  Right now you are asking available.packages about packages in all of the repositories in your getOption("repos") ...

FWIW, the file cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds that available.packages downloads in the type = "source" case is just 931 KiB.  Unserialized it is a 20659-by-16 matrix of size 10.3 MiB.  Does "350K lines" refer to the length of this matrix?

This answer shows a way t grab the version from the package webpage -- it is easy enough to remove the date stuff from the answer. There is also  https://r-hub.github.io/pkgsearch/reference/cran_package.html

How about this?
PACKAGES <- tempfile(fileext = "rds")

pkgversion <- function(package) {
  # Get list of packages from CRAN if
  #
  # - don't have local copy or
  # - local copy more than 5 minutes old.
  #
  if (
    !file.exists(PACKAGES) || 
    difftime(Sys.time(), file.mtime(PACKAGES), unit = "mins") > 5
  ) {
    download.file(
      "cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds",
      PACKAGES,
      quiet = FALSE
    )
  }
  # Read and convert to data frame.
  packages <- readRDS("PACKAGES.rds") |> data.frame()
  # Filter for specified package and return version.
  packages[packages$Package == package,]$Version
}

You could make the function more robust and efficient, but this does the job.
Sample output:
> pkgversion("dplyr")
trying URL 'cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds'
Content type 'unknown' length 953040 bytes (930 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 930 KB

[1] "1.1.4"
> pkgversion("ggplot2")
[1] "3.5.1"
> pkgversion("tidyr")
[1] "1.3.1"


This answer describes what available.packages already does - can you clarify how it is simpler?

Depends on what you want from "simpler". I think that the implementation in your question is pretty simple and I'd probably go with that. One advantage that my approach has is that the volume of data downloaded is less (930 KB versus the 10 Mb you resported).

I'm not the OP.  But note that ~10 MiB likely refers to the unserialized object: object.size(readRDS(PACKAGES)).

Good point. I did not validate this size.
